# FFMPEG Multiple Filters (Scale Video + Scale / Apply Watermark)

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-interface, scale

Can someone please tell me the proper syntax for combining the following filters into a single command? I can't seem to figure it out.

The following command is being used to scale the video.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -vf scale="'if(gt(a,4/3),1280,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,720)'" -movflags +faststart output.mp4 2>&1
```

Then, I use the following code to scale and apply the watermark.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "movie=logo.png, scale=200:-1 [wm]; [in][wm] overlay=5:main_h-overlay_h-5 [out]" output.mp4 2>&1
```

They work fine independently but every attempt I've made to combine the filter commands has been unsuccessful. Some assistance would be appreciated.

LOG

```
# ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/site/public_html/media/input.mp4 \
> -i /var/www/html/site/public_html/media/logo.png \
> -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -filter_complex "[0]scale='if(gt(a,4/3),1280,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,720)'[main];[1]scale=200:-1[wm];[main][wm]overlay=5:main_h-overlay_h-5" -movflags +faststart \
> /var/www/html/site/public_html/media/output.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2015-04-08-b926f02 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/bin --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora
  libavutil      54. 22.101 / 54. 22.101
  libavcodec     56. 34.100 / 56. 34.100
  libavformat    56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 13.101 /  5. 13.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/site/public_html/media/input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-10-17 22:26:58
  Duration: 00:00:02.40, start: 0.047891, bitrate: 2614 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 81 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-17 22:26:58
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 716x1280, 2521 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-17 22:26:58
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/var/www/html/site/public_html/media/logo.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba, 468x100, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File '/var/www/html/site/public_html/media/output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x30008a0] width not divisible by 2 (403x720)
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/html/site/public_html/media/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 30 fps (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.34.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-17 22:26:58
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc56.34.100 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 1):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -filter_complex "[0]scale='if(gt(a,4/3),1280,-2)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-2,720)'[main];[1]scale=200:-1[wm];[main][wm]overlay=5:main_h-overlay_h-5" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Filtering Intro](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still get an error message with that command similar to my other attempts to combine the filters. "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"

Comment: I have updated the post to include the log. It seems the reason may be that the scale only works with double quotes scale="'if(gt(a,4/3),1280,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,720)'" but I can't figure out how to do that in a combined filter.

Comment: @master00 It is not a quoting issue. Your expression is outputting a value that is not divisible by 2 (as mentioned by the log) which is required by libx264 when outputting YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling. [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) can ensure output is divisible by 2 with a value of `-2` instead of `-1`. See updated answer. Also, your ffmpeg is very old. Get a new version before doing anything else: [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I tried to compile a new version of FFMPEG but I get an error on make. All dependencies are installed. Any idea what this means? "X86ASM libavfilter/x86/af_afir.o
libavutil/x86/x86inc.asm:1651: error: `%macro' expects a macro name
libavutil/x86/x86inc.asm:1651: error: `%endmacro': not defining a macro
make: *** [libavfilter/x86/af_afir.o] Error 1"

Comment: @master00 Should be asked as a new question because it is a different topic than "FFMPEG Multiple Filters (Scale Video + Scale / Apply Watermark)"